# Ideas for transferring data to Web Service

Tags: c#, .net, web-services

I have an application that collects data and I need information on developing a queueing service to interact with from various web-based applications.

I had thought about utilizing a centralized database, but I think that this idea may be overkill.

Is there a global cache object at web service level that my application can access and push/pull data?

Comment: I suppose it really depends on how big a deal it is for you to loose some of the data.

Comment: @Locksfree , I cannot loose a data ...

Comment: well then either a database or a MSMQ (directly or via WCF) as pointed below sounds like a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've named a DB, other choices could be

1. Writing to a file - This will cause issues if reading/writing same time
2. MSMQ - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms711472(VS.85).aspx

They would be stable persistent stores, if its not important to be persistent, you could create a WCF service and have it store it in the `System.Runtime.Cache`

Answer (score 2):

Are you stuck with Web Services? WCF has transitional End points that can queue inbound requests for you.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms789048.aspx

If you are going to stick with web services, you can implement calls directly to the MSMQ system in .net. below is a great article from the msdn magazine describing how to use it with the .net wrapper.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164041.aspx

good luck!

Comment: @N8 , I must to use web service because I am mocking some third party asmx web service.

Comment: Ok, I would still say the MSMQ would be the best bet if you are not wanting to use a database. try this article (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164041.aspx) I'll update my answer with a link as well

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, I used MSMQ to get around it.